# Doctrine OneToOne fatal error "Maximum function nesting level ... reached"

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, fatal-error, doctrine-query

what could be the problem?

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '150' reached, aborting! in
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9faSV/

Comment: Somehow there is recursion. But without the definition of your one-to-one assocation it is impossible to solve.

Comment: Here you are: https://gist.github.com/Gamempire/6827565